# Looking for a PHP and/or Python RAD

Tags: php, python, vcl4php

I am looking for RAD like environment for PHP and/or Python free or not does not matter.

It should have a visual environment where one can use a point and click interface so that it is possible to select objects with mouse and move them around.

I have looked at Delphi4PHP. The RAD part is fantastic, but I don't like the framework on which it is based VCL4PHP (vcl4php.sourceforge.net) is crappy. Just to deploy a simple Hello world application we will have to deploy 40MB of that framework. That is just stupid.....

I looked at Eclipse but it is only a code IDE. Does not have a visual way of designing a page/window. Did I miss any plugin that supports this feature?

I was suggested to give NetBeans IDE a close look so I also looked that up, but did not find what I wanted.

I have also looked up following but none of these are true RAD:

- NuSphere PHPEd
- VS PHP for Visual Studio
- PHP Designer (not a designer by any means just a plain old IDE)

I have not been able to find any descent Python RAD tool also.

I have looked up Yes Software's Code Charge Studio (www.yessoftware.com) but it cannot be used to develop complicated applications like say for example an Accounting System or an Inventory Management App, etc.. It is useful but for very simple apps. Making changes to Visual part (referred as components by this people) is a nightmare. Finally it does not support Python.

Comment: Belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @NotMe Or [SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16649/angularjs-drag-drop-gui-builder-code-generator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python and PHP both have a binding for [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) :

- [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) for Python;
- [PHP GTK](http://gtk.php.net/) for PHP;

You can use [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) as a RADD to draw a GTK app.

GTK runs on Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

If you are looking for something embedding everything, I can think of [SPE](http://pythonide.blogspot.com/) for Python, but you really can run Glade as stand alone.

Since any picture is worth 1000 words :

[image]

I let the PHP lovers choosing their language equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I just remenbered some more tools that might be useful to you, besides WebDev:

- PHPMaker
- WaveMaker

For Python I'm gonna try the DialogBlocks later this evening.

Comment: I have looked in PHP Maker but unfortunately it is more suitable for basic CRUD functionality only.

Answer (score 2):

for python try [BoaConstructor](http://www.boa-constructor.sourceforge.net) if you come delphi background its a good start.

Comment: This looks a bit promising. But I will look into it and then only I can decide.

Answer (score 2):

[TurboPHP](http://www.turbophp.com/), and it's now open source project.

Also [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/screenshots.php) has GUI Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi4PHP is the only I know of, back in the old days I also used Macromedia (now Adobe) Dreamweaver to generate some code, and if you set up a live site it kinda acts like a RAD IDE. Kinda.

For Python, I asked a similar question a couple of hours ago, I'm also interested in knowing such tool.

Comment: Delphi4PHP is promising but really having many limitations like we cannot import an existing site into it. This is what I like the most in case of Dreamweaver as our team has to constantly add programming to existing sites.

Comment: @eyze,

Regarding Python I had heard that there was something called Visual Python but I am not able to find it anywhere.

Microsoft's Iron Pythony is nothing but crap!

If you find something useful please do PM me.

Answer (score 1):

There also [webdev](http://www.pcsoft.fr/webdev/). It can generate PHP.

Comment: I have not looked at the latest version but in the past it was not that promising and functional.

Most of the learning Material was only available in French.

I will surely check it out now that you have pointed to it!

Comment: Sorry in my previous comment I was referring to WinDev and not WebDev. I have never seen WebDev.

Comment: webdev also made by pcsoft wich is a french company.
I just know about it's existence but I have never tried, so I can not tell youy more about it

Comment: I looked up WebDev.
It is toooooo dear to purchase priced 1000+ Euros!

It is better to use something else!

Answer (score 1):

[Wingware](http://www.wingware.com/products) looks like  a pretty decent Python IDE

Comment: Thanks for the Link but I do not want an IDE only. I wand a RAD environment so that I can design the UI visually using drag-n-drop, something that is possible in RAD tools like VB and Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

I think Morfik is a RAD tool pretty much like what you're looking for.  The language you program in is not PHP or Python, though.  It uses ObjectPascal, c#, or Basic:

http://www.morfik.com

Comment: I have tried Morfik when it was in Beta stage. But was not impressed by it.
And unfortunately as you have noted it does not support PHP or Python.

Comment: Yogi, I didn't suggest that I had used Morkik or make any statement regarding its quality.  I noted that it didn't use PHP or Python.  Might I suggest that downvoting people who are making honest efforts to be helpful might be counterproductive for you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Yogi is a PITA. He is discerning and this is very helpful. Since none of these tools quite hit the mark for him when one does it will be the right one and then all of us will benefit from his studied decision.

Answer (score 0):

You should really check out Vs.php [Vs.php](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php) it is visual studio (standalone) or a visual studio plugin. Now if someone would do the same for xcode...

Comment: This is just a PHP Editor. I want a RAD tool not an editor.

Comment: what is not RAD about visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Let me elaborate on CodeCharge Studio. I think you still can consider this system. 
Personally, I've been using it to develop very complex high-load data-base driven CRM applications, with 4.x version it even generates AJAX-based code and autocomplete, ajax-form submittion are piece of cake.
With CCS you will need sometimes some tuning, but the tricks are pretty much typical. So, CodeCharge Studio is still a choice for complex applications too.

Comment: May be you are right but from my evaluation I feel it is limited. Another thing is that I framework as implemented in it is not well documented. I could not find info describing the basis of the template framework. How it works, how one can modify it outside CSS, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Delphi, you can try ExtPascal - http://code.google.com/p/extpascal/ . There is a 3rd party designer support for this framework(Delphi and Lazarus).

Answer (score 0):

I found an IDE which will allow user to visually build Python based apps. The IDE is open souce and is from Japan.

Check it out!

[link text](http://www.widestudio.org/EE/wsinfo.html)

And

[link text](http://www.widestudio.org/EE/spec.html)

I have to say that I have not used it. I just discovered it!

I am still searching for a good IDE for PHP which will allow me to build GUI visually.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score -5):

The good news is that you won't miss it as soon as you familiarize yourself with a way of work when the responsibilities are shared.

Think it over: really the programmer is the right person to assemble the user interface? I think not even in case of a desktop application.

Programmer should write good code, separated display logic, and let all the presentation things to

- information architects
- user interface/experience specialists
- **here comes you, to write the code**
- graphic designers
- sitebuilders

The -not so bad- news is that, there is no such tool for PHP and Python.

Comment: I think you need to read my profile first.

I want a RAD tool (if possible) for both PHP and Python.

I am already using Dreamweaver and it is great in many ways compared to various PHP Editors like VS.php, PHPEd, etc.

Comment: In my answer, I tryed to emphasize there is a very weak interest in RAD tools within the this field. It it were false, there would be at least a project with good momentum to develop a real RAD solution.

I still can't see why shoud a UI expert produce actual working code, even if he/she is capable to do so.

Your experience won't make you any closer to a tool practically not existing. Even if you "want" it. This is a hard fact, try to accept and please don't require me to read your resume to post my opinion. Tywm.